# How can i calculate for the estimated completion time of both process

Tags: algorithm, process, multiprocessing, cpu, operation

A certain computer system runs in a multi-programming environment using a non-preemptive
algorithm. In this system, two processes A and B are stored in the process queue,
and A has a higher priority than B. The table below shows estimated execution time for each
process; for example, process A uses CPU, I/O, and then CPU sequentially for 30, 60, and 30
milliseconds respectively. Which of the following is the estimated time in milliseconds
to complete both A and B? Here, the multi-processing overhead of OS is negligibly
small. In addition, both CPU and I/O operations can be executed concurrently, but I/O
operations for A and B cannot be performed in parallel.

UNIT : millisecond

```
                 CPU                    I/O                  CPU
```

A_______________30___________________60_________________30

B_______________45___________________45__________________--

Please help me.. i need to explain this in front of the class tomorrow but i cant seem get the idea of it...

Comment: by the way... the correct answer is 135...please explain how can i get this... thankyou in advance

Comment: I added a brief explanation why this happens so you can accpet the answer :-)

Comment: thankyou so much ^^ i appreciate  it alot

Comment: Please see the answer of Matt for a step by step solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A has the highest priority, but since the system is non-preemptive, this is only a tiebreaker when both processes need a resource at the same time.

At t=0, A gets the CPU for 30 ms, B waits as it needs the CPU.

At t=30, A releases the CPU, B gets the CPU for 45 ms, while A gets the I/O for 60 ms.

At t=75, the CPU sits idle as B is waiting for A to finish I/O, and A is not ready to use the CPU.

At t=90, A releases I/O and gets the CPU for another 30 ms, while B gets the I/O for 45 ms.

At t=120, A releases the CPU and is finished.

At t=135, B releases I/O and is finished.

Answer (score 2):

It takes the longest path:

Non-preemptive multitasking or cooperative multitasking means that the process is kind of sharing a.e. the CPU time. In the worst case they use the worst time to achieve theire task.

**CPU:**
B = 45 is longer than A=30

45 +

**I/O**
A = 60 and B = 45

45 + 60

**CPU again:**
A = 30

*45 + 60 + 30 = 135*

Comment: Thankyou so much! now i understand. you saved my life :D

Comment: why does it took the longest path?

Comment: Because of the the multitasking strategy. (cooperative multitasking)

Comment: See Matt's answer for a clean step by step solution.

Answer (score 1):

i will explain in brief and please elaborate for your classroom discussion:
For your answer :135
when Process A waits for the I/O task,the CPU time will be given to Process B. so the complete time for process A and B would be

Process A (CPU )+ Process A I/O and Process B CPU + Process B I/O
30+60+45 = 135 ms